# Is it possible to load a Google Chart on a webpage before the entire document is ready (on any of the new GoogleCharts versions)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

At the moment, I'm stuck using version 1 of GoogleCharts because as far as I'm aware, it's the only version that will work when I need to be able to generate a chart before the page has loaded.  I understand that generally it isn't good to do this, but it is necessary in this case.

I'm loading a long scrolling page of dynamically created content where I want each chart to appear as it loads, so that the entirety of the dynamically created content does not need to be loaded before any charts (the ones on the top) load.

So far the only solution I've found is using version 1 of google charts, but this version lacks functionality I wish to add. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hey, Colbi. What are the features you need to implement? Also, it's not clear to me why you can't generate the charts on the client side. Finally, have you tried something to use a recent version of Google Charts? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply!

Comment: I apologize if this is a dumb question, but how would i generate it client side?  The problem is that whenever I use the newer version and load the charts with the callback function, the charts do not appear until the entire document is ready, and then they all appear at the same time.   From what i've read, this is because the google OnLoadCallback function waits until the document is considered ready, for the charts to be drawn

Comment: From what I've read, the setOnloadCallback() have nothing to do with your document load, it just wait for the google chart pakage loaded and call your callback function. I wonder if along to the page contents, you are loading some google chart pakagea.

Comment: " I wonder if along to the page contents, you are loading some google chart pakagea." Could you please explain what you mean by this?  I saw 2 other answers on here that said the setOnloadCallback() does wait for the document to be ready, and in my testing that is what's happening unless there is some other explanation I and the others explanations I've read that isn't being considered.  Thanks for your response trgiangvp3

Comment: I meant to draw a chart, you have to load particular pakage like this `google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});`
This will make a request to google server to load chart library. So I think if you preload all neccessary libraries, your chart will be drawn right at the time your chart data is get.

Answer (score 3):

as stated in the docs for the [callback](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#Callback)...

> The loader will also wait for the document to finish loading before calling the callback.

but this only means it will wait for the static document to load,
meaning whatever content is on the page when it is first opened,
and not dynamically created content

regardless, if you're loading a bunch of stuff, all in succession,
the browser is not going to be able to keep up,
and will wait until processing has finished, to show the results
which is why everything shows up at once

if you want certain content to display, before other content is displayed,
you need to delay adding more content,
until you have confirmation the previous content has loaded

for instance, when drawing the first chart,
wait for its `'ready'` event to fire,
before drawing the next chart
(or `'animationfinish'`)

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'animationfinish', drawNextChart);
```

you can produce the same results for dynamic content using `setTimeout`
which will allow the browser to take a break,
display what it has so far, then continue processing...
(even if the timeout is set to 1m)

```
window.setTimeout(drawNextContent, 1);
```

see following working snippet,
each chart is drawn after the previous has finished...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y');
    data.addRows([
      [new Date("2017-08-16T06:00:00.000Z"), 145289],
      [new Date("2017-08-16T05:00:00.000Z"), 138370],
      [new Date("2017-08-16T04:00:00.000Z"), 117605],
      [new Date("2017-08-16T03:00:00.000Z"), 81268],
      [new Date("2017-08-16T02:00:00.000Z"), 59815],
      [new Date("2017-08-16T01:00:00.000Z"), 51899]
    ]);

    var options = {
      animation: {
        duration: 1000,
        startup: true
      }
    };

    drawChart0();

    function drawChart0() {
      var container = document.getElementById('charts').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'animationfinish', drawChart1);
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawChart1() {
      var container = document.getElementById('charts').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'animationfinish', drawChart2);
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawChart2() {
      var container = document.getElementById('charts').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'animationfinish', drawContent0);
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawContent0() {
      var container = document.getElementById('charts').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('content-template').innerHTML;
      window.setTimeout(drawContent1, 1000);
    }

    function drawContent1() {
      var container = document.getElementById('charts').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('content-template').innerHTML;
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="charts"></div>

<script id="content-template" type="text/html">
  <div><h3>Dynamic Content</h3></div>
  <div>shows after charts finish</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason Google Charts waits for the document loading to complete before proceeding with the callbacks is that the container element you reference when you create a chart must exist and be visible at the time you draw the chart.  But if you want to take responsibility for ensuring the container is ready, you can now (with version 45.2) choose to avoid the wait, by adding `'ignoreWindowOnLoad': true` to your load settings.

Comment: Thanks! I'd add that setting and set it to true in my options for the chart?

Comment: Got it working. That setting is a life saver!! Thank you